# Is there way to call a Bamboo build plan once a deployment plan is completed?

Tags: bamboo

I was wondering if there is any way to trigger a Bamboo build plan, once a deployment plan has executed successfully?

We have a separate build plan, which will be used to trigger Sanity, so requirement is once deployment is done, Sanity plan should be triggered.
Searched but didn't find relevant info.
Bamboo Box: Windows

Aman

Answer (score 5):

Atlassian has just released the [Bamboo After Deployment Trigger](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassianlab.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-after-deployment-trigger-plugin/server/overview) as a labs add-on, which precisely covers your use case by adding a *trigger to run plan when deployment project was deployed*.

Answer (score 0):

see this link..
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/245008/triggering-integration-tests-after-deployment

there is no straight forward way yet. All items in above link are a workaround way of doing it. The easiest way would involve modify a source code and then watch for that source code to trigger that other plan. You can create a separate repo or in same repo watch for a file change in one plan and ignore that same file in first plan.